# How to resize two dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same structure. For the sake of simplicity, I paste one and re-create the other one

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0],
               '400.0': [13.909261, 7.758734, 3.513627, 2.095409, 1.628918, 0.782643, 0.278548, 0.160153, -0.155895, -0.152373, -0.147820, -0.023997, 0.010729, 0.006050, 0.002356],
               '401.0': [14.581624, 8.173803, 3.757856, 2.223524, 1.695623, 0.818065, 0.300235, 0.173674, -0.145402, -0.144456, -0.142969, -0.022471, 0.010802, 0.006181, 0.002641],
               '402.0': [15.253988, 8.588872, 4.002085, 2.351638, 1.762327, 0.853486, 0.321922, 0.187195, -0.134910, -0.136539, -0.138118, -0.020945, 0.010875, 0.006313, 0.002927],
               '403.0': [15.633908, 8.833914, 4.146499, 2.431543, 1.798185, 0.874350, 0.333470, 0.192128, -0.130119, -0.134795, -0.136049, -0.019307, 0.012037, 0.006674, 0.003002],
               '404.0': [15.991816, 9.066159, 4.283401, 2.507818, 1.831721, 0.894119, 0.344256, 0.196415, -0.125758, -0.133516  , -0.134189, -0.017659, -0.013281,0.007053, 0.003061],
               '405.0': [16.349725, 9.298403, 4.420303, 2.584094, 1.865257, 0.913887, 0.355041, 0.200702, -0.121396, -0.132237, -0.132330, -0.016012, 0.014525, 0.007433, 0.003120]
               })

df2 = df1.drop('depth', axis=1) 
df3 = df2*0.85
df3.depth = df1.depth

depth_1 = df1.depth - 0.8
depth_3 = depth_1 + 0.3
```

So now I have `depth_1` ranging from 0.8 to 2.2 and `depth_3` from 1.1 to 2.5 I need to recreate `df1` and `df3` so they both range from the minimum of `depth_1` to the maximum of `depth_3`, that is from 0.8 to 2.5.

That way the last 3 rows of `df1` and first three of `df3` the will be filled with NaN or zero.

So my output should result in something like this for `df1` for example:

```
        400.0      401.0      402.0      403.0      404.0      405.0  depth
0   13.909261  14.581624  15.253988  15.633908  15.991816  16.349725    0.8
1    7.758734   8.173803   8.588872   8.833914   9.066159   9.298403    0.9
2    3.513627   3.757856   4.002085   4.146499   4.283401   4.420303    1.0
3    2.095409   2.223524   2.351638   2.431543   2.507818   2.584094    1.1
4    1.628918   1.695623   1.762327   1.798185   1.831721   1.865257    1.2
5    0.782643   0.818065   0.853486   0.874350   0.894119   0.913887    1.3
6    0.278548   0.300235   0.321922   0.333470   0.344256   0.355041    1.4
7    0.160153   0.173674   0.187195   0.192128   0.196415   0.200702    1.5
8   -0.155895  -0.145402  -0.134910  -0.130119  -0.125758  -0.121396    1.6
9   -0.152373  -0.144456  -0.136539  -0.134795  -0.133516  -0.132237    1.7
10  -0.147820  -0.142969  -0.138118  -0.136049  -0.134189  -0.132330    1.8
11  -0.023997  -0.022471  -0.020945  -0.019307  -0.017659  -0.016012    1.9
12   0.010729   0.010802   0.010875   0.012037  -0.013281   0.014525    2.0
13   0.006050   0.006181   0.006313   0.006674   0.007053   0.007433    2.1
14   0.002356   0.002641   0.002927   0.003002   0.003061   0.003120    2.2
15   0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0         2.3
16   0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0         2.4
17   0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0         2.5
```

And similarly, `df3` will have the first three rows either `NaN` or zero.

How can I do it?

Comment: last 3 rows of df1? That doesn't sound right to me... seems like a lot of data is out of range here.

Comment: You can use 

`df1.loc[:, df1.columns!='depth'] = df1.loc[:, df1.columns!='depth']*0.85` instead of go create `df2` and `df3`.

Comment: @user32185, that's very useful, thank you! You can re-edit the post if you want

Comment: @coldspeed, it is right because the df1 starts from 0.8 and ends at 2.1, so the depth range from 2.2 and 2.5 will be empty. Likewise the first three of df3 because it's shifted for 0.3 m downwards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace them with zeros you can use `between` and do this

```
top = depth_3.max()
bottom = depth_1.min()
df1[~df1.depth.between(bottom, top)] = 0
df3[~df3.depth.between(bottom, top)] = 0
```

Edit: as mentioned in your comment if you don't want to overwrite the depth you can use

```
top = depth_3.max()
bottom = depth_1.min()
df1_cols = df1.columns.difference(["depth"])
df1.loc[~df1.depth.between(bottom, top), df1_cols] = 0
```

Comment: that's very elegant and concise! thank you so much! The only question is how do I avoid the 5 rows full of zeros also in the depth column in the output?

Comment: See my edit for an example of how that would work on df1

Comment: thank you again, I may have not explained it well. Both df1 and df3 should result in a range between 0.8 to 2.5. That means that the df1 should have the first three rows empty (ranging from 0.8 to 2.2), and the df3 the last 3 ones (from 1.1 to 2.5). According to the depth range of each, but both dataframes should have the same shape and re-aranged values from 0.8 to 2.5

Comment: I think the only thing that really needs to change then if for you to assign depth as the adjusted values rather than the raw ones and the rest of the suggestions in the post should work

Comment: something like `df1["depth"] = df1.depth - 0.8` after depth_1 has been assigned. If that doesn't get you to your answer try posing it as a new question with where you're up to.

Comment: I cannot delete it. I'll vote it as a solved and useful post. I'd just kindly ask you to help me if you don't mind